# Django built-in login failed from react

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

django

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class UserLoginView(GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        user = serializer.validate(request.data)

        if user is None:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            user.before_last_login = user.last_login
            login(request, user)
            user.save()
            user = UserSerializer(user)
            return Response(data={'id': user.data['id'], 'img': user.data['image']}
                            , status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

react

```
const res = await axios.post(`${APIURL}/account/login/`, {
  id: id,
  password: pwd,
});
```

when I try to login from react, I get suceessful response(
`Response(data={'id': user.data['id'], 'img': user.data['image']}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)`
) but failes. User is still annonymousUser in django. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your React frontend is hosted on a different server. The `login()` method just adds the user's session id to the browser storage and then uses middleware to attach this session id to requests.

If your React frontend is hosted on a different server, it will have no knowledge of this session cookie and it will not be appended to your `axios()` requests. Instead you need add the users token (if using token based authentication) to your `Response()` and cache this in your browser. You can then append this token in subsequent `axios()` calls which will identify the user to your Django backend.